# R POSIXct date difference produce artificial decimal places

Tags: r, posixct, difftime

I have a POSIXct date column, and try to baseline it. However, I found the `difftime()` (or just `-`) operation produce artificial decimal places that should never exist.

```
>center_coor[,dateTime]
[1] "2023-06-12 12:44:00.375 BST" "2023-06-12 12:44:00.390 BST" "2023-06-12 12:44:00.417 BST"

>center_coor[,difftime(dateTime,dateTime[1])]
Time differences in secs
[1]  0.00000000  0.01500010  0.04299998
```

I definitely don't want those artificial decimal places. How could this happen? and how can I disable them in `difftime()` other than using `round()` afterwards?

**Updated 1 using dput()** really make no change to the data and just give all the artificial decimal places.

```
>center_coor[,dateTime]]%>%dput()
structure(c(1686570240.375, 1686570240.39, 1686570240.418), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GB")

>center_coor[,difftime(dateTime,dateTime[1])]]%>%dput()
structure(c(0, 0.0150001049041748, 0.0429999828338623), class = "difftime", units = "secs")
```

For a reproducible example, you can most certainly copy and convert the characters provided into a POSIXct column llike below, and then take the difference. Again, it produce artificial decimal places.

```
>temp=data.table(dateTime=c("2023-06-12 12:44:00.375 BST", "2023-06-12 12:44:00.390 BST", "2023-06-12 12:44:00.417 BST")%>%as.POSIXct(Time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz='GB'))
>temp[,difftime(dateTime,dateTime[1])]%>%dput()
structure(c(0, 0.0150001049041748, 0.0420000553131104), class = "difftime", units = "secs")
```

Comment: where does center_coor come from? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with dput() and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: printed values may hide crucial information. especially in cases in which decimals are the issue.

Comment: R has an option that governs _default_ number of decimals printed in datetime obkects: use `options(digits.secs=0)` to switch from your value ot three to zero.

Comment: dput() results and a reproducible example updated.

Comment: This is also related to how R and most programming languages handle floating-point numbers (tech refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). For example, see that `0.1 + 0.05 == 0.15` counterintuitively returns false, because numbers with precision can not always be perfectly defined.

Comment: Ultimately, I think this is not a bug or a programming _problem_, per se, it is a misunderstanding of how to deal with floating-point numbers. When dealing with high-precision numbers (whether "normal" numbers or `difftime` or similar), if you need it to be so-many-digits in a report, then you need to force that restriction using `sprintf` (or perhaps `round`, though not always). If you need to test for how close two numbers are, with high-precision it occasionally necessary to test for a tolerance in difference, such as `abs(x - y) < 1e-6`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the response. I understand it more now, but still don't understand why the decimal places increased. In fact, I don't need that many digits, and would like to keep them as 3 as originally. What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: `round(., 3)` the differences, but even then you can run into some small problems here and there. Why do you need to keep it 3 in your raw data? Is it that you need it rendered (in a report or plot) or that you want to change your data to reflect an expectation/assumption about the data?

Comment: @r2evans I just want keep the precision, and run calculation based on those data.

Comment: What's wrong with "doing nothing" keeping the numbers "as-is"? That is, if you round them in order to get the 3-digits you think is more accurate, then you might be imposing change in the direction-of-differences (above/below a threshold), altering your takeaway. Said differently, once you recognize that `0.390 - 0.375 == 0.015` is counterintuitively false but `abs((0.390 - 0.375) - 0.015) < 1e-9` is true, perhaps you can continue with the steps that you need?